# How to start a Rails server forever on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, deployment, ubuntu-14.04

I have uploaded my Rails app on my Ubuntu server, where I want to keep my Rails server running so that any one can access it at any time.

I tried the command below to run my app:

`rails server --binding=oditek.in  -p 8888`

Please help me to make this possible.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the your question? The above command isn't working? Is it giving any errors?

Comment: @sshah : I am explaining very simply .I want to run rails server in my ubuntu server where i have uploaded all my rails app.And this rails app will run forever.

Comment: I'd suggest you don't user the default Rails server for deployment in production. You can try using Passenger: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-rails-and-nginx-with-passenger-on-ubuntu
This will allow your server to be up and running "forever".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try following option to run the server in background.

```
rails s -d ## With default Port.
rails s -p 8888 -d ## With Custom port.
```

**Or**

```
nohup rails s &
```

**Or**

You can also configure your project with `Nginx + Passenger`

Comment: @ Amit ;i am accessing my ubuntu machine remotely.If i will run your command and stop my system it will run or not.

Comment: @satya It will run because this process runs in background.

Comment: `nohup rails s &` worked fine for me on DigitalOcean